# C# - Get value from another class

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I'm having problems working with multiple classes on c#. I have a class That have a value and a method like this:

```
Class class1
{
    int curValue = 0;
    Public int curValue
    {
       get {return curValue; } set{curValue = value; }
    }

    Class1()
    {

    }

    public void Work()
    {
        while(//condition)
             curValue++;
        //some other code
    }
}
```

And i need two times get value from this class to two form:
the first form has a button that activate class1's variable

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    OnButtonBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 a = new Class1();
        a.Work();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(a);
        form2.show()
    }
}
```

The problem happen when I create another Form2 where take the value from class1 to a label:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Class1 b;
        public Form2(Class1 input)
        {
            b = input;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
             lb.Text = b.curValue;
        }
    }
```

The label's text has not increased as I wanted. I even checked by creating a similar label on Form1 and it work well. Please help me make it work on Form2, Thank you!

Comment: In the code You posted, You create a new instance of `Class1` on each button click, so the timer is set to 0 and then increased to 1 each time.

Comment: *"The label's text has not increased as I wanted"*  What did you want it to be? What was it?

Comment: Have you checked the form2_load code is being executed?

Answer (score 1):

In the code You posted, You create a new instance of `Class1` on each button click, so the timer is set to *0* and then increased to *1* each time.

If You want to increase the same counter on each button click, You can put the line `Class1 a = new Class1();` outside the `OnButtonBtn_Click` method.

There are some other issues with that code, but they're not in the scope of this question. I suppose it's a test code, not an actual program.